# Left Join - Unknown Column?

Tags: mysql

Can you assist me with my query?  I keep receiving an error that states "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'cdata.customerid' in 'on clause'"

If I want to attach the left join data where the customer id's match from customerdata table and order table, how can I achieve this? I must not understand at what point SQL allows data to become accessible by different parts of the query.

```
select 

cdata.customerid, 
cdata.affiliate, 
cdata.firstname,
cdata.address1,
cdata.address2,
cdata.city,
cdata.state,
cdata.postalcode,
cdata.emailaddress,
cdata.active


from customerdata cdata, order a

left join
(select 
a.transactiondate, 
sum(a.TransactionAmount), 
a.id 
from order a
group by a.id) 

txns on a.id = cdata.customerid

where cdata.active = "A";
```

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen `order` used that way before; is that a table in your schema?

Comment: @Uuerdo order is apparently the name of the table.

Comment: Why is your `ON` clause for the join with `txns` referring to `a` and `cdata`, but not `txns`?

Comment: Using backticks on table/column names that overlap with MySQL keywords is helpful to prevent this kind of confusion. Eg ``from `order` a``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `on` clause you have to specify fields that belong to the tables which are taking part in `join` clause. So, if you are joining `cdata` with the `txns` subquery, you have to probably join on `txns.id` and `cdata.customerid`. You probably also wanted to get your sum out of your subquery, so you have to include this field in your main `SELECT` clause. And you probably have to specify `transactiondate` field in your `group by` clause, at least this is necessary for ORACLE DB, I am not sure if this is the case for MySQL:

```
select 

cdata.customerid, 
cdata.affiliate, 
cdata.firstname,
cdata.address1,
cdata.address2,
cdata.city,
cdata.state,
cdata.postalcode,
cdata.emailaddress,
cdata.active,
txns.tsum,
txns.transactiondate 

from customerdata cdata

left join
(select 
 a.transactiondate, 
 sum(a.TransactionAmount) tsum, 
 a.id 
 from order a
 group by a.id, a.transactiondate) txns 
on txns.id = cdata.customerid

where cdata.active = "A";
```

Answer (score 0):

The JOIN references the table 'order' and the table 'txns', 'cdata' is not involved here, so within the context of the join cdata.customerid does not exist.

Comment: If I want to attach the left join data where the customer id's match from customerdata table and order table, how can I achieve this?  I must not be understanding at what point SQL allows data to become accessible by different parts of the query.